# Hiding column in jQuery dataTables

Tags: datatables

I have problem hiding jQuery datatable column. I want that column to retrieve data but I don't want it to be shown on the display page. I want to hide my column no 8 so from CSS I tried hiding it and it gives me collapsable div.

[image: image getting + icon on display page]

Below is my code for data table and class for hiding is "hideCol".

```js
 var userTable = $('#user').dataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax":"admin/getData.php",
      "responsive" : true,
      "lengthMenu": [10, 25],
      "paginationType" : "input",
      columns: [
              { data:'param0'},
              { data: 'param1' },
              { data: 'param2' },
              { data: 'param3' },
              { data: 'param4' },
              { data: 'param5' },
              { data: 'param6' },
              { data: 'param7'},
          ],
      fnRowCallback:function(nRow,aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
        var seenReportedVal =Number($('td:eq(7)', nRow).text());
        $('td:eq(7)', nRow).addClass('hideCol');
        if(seenReportedVal==0)
        {
         $(nRow).addClass('bold');
        }
      },
       "columnDefs": [
                       { "visible": false, "targets": 7 }
                     ],
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

try using this code

```
var userTable = $('#user').dataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax":"admin/getData.php",
      "responsive" : true,
      "lengthMenu": [10, 25],
      "paginationType" : "input",
      columns: [
              { data:'param0'},
              { data: 'param1' },
              { data: 'param2' },
              { data: 'param3' },
              { data: 'param4' },
              { data: 'param5' },
              { data: 'param6' },
              { data: 'param7'},
          ],
       "columnDefs": [
                       { "visible": false, "targets": [7] }
                     ],
    });
```

Comment: I tried with your answer it did not work . I tried this commented"responsive":true and it started working . I was using it in order to make datatable responsive . Thanks alot for your answer once again  :)

Comment: At first this solution did not work for me, but then I noticed that I had left the attribute visible: "false" in the column list, leftover from a failed attempt at an invisible column.  Once I cleaned up my mess, the column was invisible.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [visible](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) property of columns.
I suggest enclose object attributes with quotes e.g. "columns", "data" or "visible".

```
"columns": [
          { "data":'param0'},
          { "data": 'param1', "visible": false},
          { "data": 'param2'},
          { "data": 'param3'},
          { "data": 'param4'},
          { "data": 'param5'},
          { "data": 'param6'},
          { "data": 'param7'},
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already solved your problem, but since i had the same problem i will share with you at least my solution.

It looks you are using dataTable in Responsive Mode, so based on that, if you want to hide a column you have to apply specific css class for it, based on your need. You apply to the th element associated to the column, and you have your problem solved.

More info about the different css classes can be found [here](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes#Special-classes).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this with some css. Might be helpful for others.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
                 {"sClass": "dt_col_hide", "aTargets": [3]}
              ],
```

dt_col_hide is a css class and it will hide column indexed 3 in this case.

```
.dt_col_hide{display: none;}
```

or

```
.dt_col_hide{visibility:  hidden;}
```

as per your requirement.

Comment: That was the only way I managed to hide the column, thanks for sharing your solution.